# Vue 2.0 - How passing function to child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have one issue. I want to pass function link to the child component. It's working but in HTML I get that code. It's correct how improve it?

I have Vue instance

```
app = new Vue({
    ... some code
    data: {
      onAppClose: null,
      onAppSend: null
    }
})
```

I want to add from global window any function. Or register function in Vue instance

`app.onSend = () => console.log('data')`

And pass this function to child

```
<div id="app">
        <dynamsoft-component v-if="displayComponent" 
            :docs="docs"
            :onAppSend="onSend"
            :onAppClose="onClose"
        ></dynamsoft-component>
    </div>
```

But I get this HTML template in console

```
<div id="app">
 <div onappsend="()=>{}" onappclose="function (data) {
    console.warn('dwdawad')
    console.log('data')
}"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never used Vue.js before now..
But having a look at the how to on their site, this seems to work

In Vue style guide have recommendations about props naming
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Prop-name-casing-strongly-recommended

```js
Vue.component('dynamsoft-component', {
  props: ['onAppSend'],
  template: '<button v-on:click="buttonclick">click me</button>',
  methods: {
    buttonclick(e){
      // Check if onAppSend is defined.
      if(Boolean(this.onAppSend)){
        this.onAppSend();
      }
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    onSend: function(){
      console.log('child clicked');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  <dynamsoft-component :on-app-send="onSend"></dynamsoft-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You example code is not making a lot of sense - do you want to add a listener not a div or pass a function to a child component?`

I assume the latter. Vue has [custom events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) for that .

Parent template:

```
<div v-on:appsend="someMethod" v-on:appclose="someOtherMethod"></div>
```

Parent component methods:

```
methods: {
  someOtherMethod: function (data) {
    console.warn('dwdawad')
    console.log('data')
  },
  // ...
}
```

And then emit form the child:

```
this.$emit('appclose', {id: 'whatever'} /*pass data here*/)
```

---

Edit:

I still don't see how those functions would end up directly in the template, but the real problem is: HTML is not case-sensitive. so `:onAppSend` becomes `:onappsend`. You have to use kebap-case: `:on-app-send`. Vue will convert it to `onAppSend` in the component.

Comment: it's not should add in HTML template. On codepen works well

Comment: I don't understand what you are tying to say, sorry.